# Twitter OAuth fails signature validation on different domain with same code

Tags: php, twitter, oauth

I wrote a "Sign in with Twitter" option for my webapp on my local machine using this Twitter OAuth library - https://docs.google.com/View?docID=dcf2dzzs_2339fzbfsf4 and it all works great. But when I move the code to the actual production server it fails on getting a Request Token (a.k.a. the first step) with a simple "Failed to validate oauth signature and token".

What doesn make sense to me is the fact that it works flawlessly on local machine but it fails miserably on the production server, keeping in mind that they are configured identically.

So the question comes down to - **what possible differences could there be for twitter when  receiving my request from a different domain?** (yes, I did change the Application Setting on twitter.com but that a) doesn't make a difference b) doesn't seem to matter).

Note: PHP on Apache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://groups.google.com/group/twitter-development-talk/browse_thread/thread/aadee92bc5c34f29?pli=1

Turns out my server time was 4 days in the past. xD
Setting it properly fixed everything.